# Linq Expression to generic - how

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I want to convert this to a generic type:

```
using System.Linq.Expression
using System.Collections.Generic

public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(
                          params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = All;
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        // query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    return query;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, how would i do this?

Comment: What is: "doesn't seem to work"?  Is there a runtime exception, a compiler error, an improper result, or something else?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the generic parameter to AllIncluding - should possibly be AllIncluding<T> (unless the T is defined in the containing class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Include` method is available only on `DbQuery<T>` so you have to cast the query to it using a direct cast or the `as` operand or use the method [DbExtensions.Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236.aspx):

```
public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = All as DbQuery<T>;
    if (query == null)
    {
       return All;
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        // query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a using for `System.Data.Entity`;

Entity Framework 4.1 includes the strongly typed version of `Include`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(VS.103).aspx

It's an extension method.